# Why distinct in LINQ does not work for this case?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this comparer for my object `Tenant`

```
public class TenantComparer : IEqualityComparer<Tenant>
{
    // Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal.
    public bool Equals(Tenant x, Tenant y)
    {

        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public int GetHashCode(Tenant tenant)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(tenant, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        int hashProductName = tenant.Name == null ? 0 : tenant.Name.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product.
        return hashProductName;
    }
}
```

Now, I have a table with some tenants and some of them have the same name. I want to fetch those who are distinct  order by name:

```
public static List<Tenant> GetTenantListOrderyByNameASC()
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var tenantsList = (from t in db.Tenants
                       select t).Distinct().OrderBy( x => x.Name ).ToList();

    return tenantsList;
}
```

But it still shows the tenants with the same names...

Can you please tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide comparer explicitly, which at the moment you do not:

```
var tenantsList = (from t in db.Tenants
                   select t)
    .Distinct(new TenantComparer())
    .OrderBy( x => x.Name )
    .ToList();
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also need some trick to be able to return is as `List<Tenant>`: `var tenantsList = (from t in db.Tenants                           select t).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList().Distinct(new TenantComparer()).ToList();` - seems strange to use ToList() twice but otherwise I receive `Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Distinct'.`